# How to collect a non-predetermined set of characters in C?

Tags: c, loops, character

I have a textbook exercise right after looping and using char values (meaning that I can't use arrays and strings).

As per the exercise, I'll (the user) will have to make the user enter a set of chars

For example "IamaDinosaur" and then find the letter with the highest ASCII value.

How do I go about looping a `scanf()` to let the user enter `char` values until the user hits enter? And then how are the values compared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use `getch()`, then just as folks suggest you can of course use `scanf()` and just keep on scanning until it fails, or reads a newline:

```
char max = 0, here;
while(scanf("%c", &here) == 1 && here != '\n')
    if(here > max)
        max = here;
printf("max='%c'\n", max);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering however, when the characters are entered by the user, does the computer read them left to right? Say  if the user enters "Aa", in this case I want the program to return A because it's mentioned first. I tried restricting the while loop with an if statement `if ( (here>max) && (fabs (( (int)here-(int)max )) != 32) )` but it returned the highest ascii val instead. Any input re: this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `getc` maybe ?

```
int ch;
int max = EOF;
while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
    if (max < ch)
        max = ch;
```

Obviously you could go the `scanf("%c")` route.

Comment: Ah see, I'm supposed to use elementary functions, so I can't use getc, but is it safe to assume that collecting the char using scanf(%c) within a while restricted to EOF would do the same thing?

Comment: @Louis93 What are "elementary" functions ? For all practical purposes `getc` will be faster and will have fewer caveats than `scanf`. Basically in some form or the other `scanf` must end up calling `getc`.

Comment: so far, the textbook has gone up to mathematical functions (also rounding, ceil, floor), printf and scanf. I'm trying to do what the textbook expects... I'll give it a shot and update in a bit using just scanf.

Comment: @Louis93 Just curious, what textbook is that ?